Minecraft Mod Item that inherits Trident property not working
So I made a custom item for a mod that should allow the player to propel themselves to wherever they are looking similar to the trident with a riptide enchantment. So I tried grabbing the code for it and modified it to my item so it won't require the enchantment anymore. Problem is, it isn't working and not even giving a success on right-click
this is what I tried:
```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import net.minecraft.sounds.SoundEvent;
import net.minecraft.sounds.SoundEvents;
import net.minecraft.sounds.SoundSource;
import net.minecraft.stats.Stats;
import net.minecraft.util.Mth;
import net.minecraft.world.InteractionHand;
import net.minecraft.world.InteractionResultHolder;
import net.minecraft.world.effect.MobEffectInstance;
import net.minecraft.world.effect.MobEffects;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.EquipmentSlot;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.LivingEntity;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.MoverType;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.ai.attributes.Attribute;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.ai.attributes.AttributeModifier;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.ai.attributes.Attributes;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.player.Player;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.projectile.AbstractArrow;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.projectile.ThrownTrident;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.world.item.UseAnim;
import net.minecraft.world.item.enchantment.EnchantmentHelper;
import net.minecraft.world.level.Level;
import net.minecraft.world.phys.Vec3;


public class YeetItem extends Item {

    public YeetItem(Item.Properties properties) {
        super(properties);
    } 


    @Override
    public UseAnim getUseAnimation(ItemStack pStack) {
    return UseAnim.SPEAR;
    }

    @Override
    public int getUseDuration(ItemStack stack) {
        return 72000;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseUsing(ItemStack pStack, Level pLevel, LivingEntity pEntityLiving, int pTimeLeft) {
        if (pEntityLiving instanceof Player player) {
            int useDuration = this.getUseDuration(pStack) - pTimeLeft;
            if (useDuration >= 10) {
                player.awardStat(Stats.ITEM_USED.get(this));
            
                float forceMultiplier = 2.5F;
                float force = forceMultiplier;
            
                float yaw = player.getYRot();
                float pitch = player.getXRot();
                float x = -(float)Math.sin(yaw * 0.017453292F) * (float)Math.cos(pitch * 0.017453292F);
                float y = -(float)Math.sin(pitch * 0.017453292F);
                float z = (float)Math.cos(yaw * 0.017453292F) * (float)Math.cos(pitch * 0.017453292F);
                float yeet = Mth.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
                float yeet2 = 3.0F * force;
                x *= yeet2 / yeet;
                y *= yeet2 / yeet;
                z *= yeet2 / yeet;
                player.push(x, y, z);
                player.startAutoSpinAttack(20);
                if (player.onGround()) {
                   player.move(MoverType.SELF, new Vec3(0.0, 1.1999999284744263, 0.0));
               }

            
                pLevel.playSound(null, player, SoundEvents.TRIDENT_RIPTIDE_1, SoundSource.PLAYERS, 1.0F, 1.0F);

            
                pStack.hurtAndBreak(1, player, (p_43388_) -> {
                    p_43388_.broadcastBreakEvent(player.getUsedItemHand());
                });
                if (!player.getAbilities().instabuild) {
                    player.getInventory().removeItem(pStack);
                }

                player.awardStat(Stats.ITEM_USED.get(this));
            } 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hurtEnemy(ItemStack pStack, LivingEntity pTarget, LivingEntity pAttacker) {
        pStack.hurtAndBreak(1, pAttacker, (p_43414_) -> {
            p_43414_.broadcastBreakEvent(EquipmentSlot.MAINHAND);
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
     public InteractionResultHolder<ItemStack> use(Level pLevel, Player pPlayer, InteractionHand pUsedHand) {
        ItemStack $$3 = pPlayer.getItemInHand(pUsedHand);
        if ($$3.getDamageValue() >= $$3.getMaxDamage() - 1) {
        return InteractionResultHolder.fail($$3);
        } else if (EnchantmentHelper.getRiptide($$3) > 0 && !pPlayer.isInWaterOrRain()) {
            return InteractionResultHolder.fail($$3);
        } else {
            pPlayer.startUsingItem(pUsedHand);
            return InteractionResultHolder.consume($$3);
        }
    }
}
```

this is supposed to allow the player to hold right-click when holding the item and when they release it, it will propel them forward similar to a trident (with riptide enchantment)
